# CONDITIONAL STATEMENT - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I need to build a query with 3 conditionals, but all the forms tried was returned to me the three tables, even though they had null values.

I tried to do with left join and left outer join, but it didn't work

How do I get back only the table that has data entered?

```
SELECT * FROM tb_associado AS associado 
INNER JOIN tb_ProdutoComercial AS comercial ON associado.id_prodcomerc_a = comercial.id_prodcomerc
INNER JOIN tb_ProdAnsS4E AS sq ON comercial.id_ProdutoS4E_c = sq.nu_CodProdutoS4E
INNER JOIN tb_meiopagto AS tmp ON associado.id_meiopagto_a = tmp.id_meiopagto

LEFT JOIN tb_pgtoboleto AS tb ON (associado.id_associado = tb.cd_associado_pb AND tmp.cd_codmeiopagto = '3' AND tb.cd_associado_pb <> NULL) -- cond 1

LEFT JOIN tb_pgtocartao AS tc ON (associado.id_associado = tc.cd_associado_pc AND tmp.cd_codmeiopagto = '1' AND tc.cd_associado_pc <> NULL) -- cond 2

LEFT JOIN tb_pgtodebito AS td ON (associado.id_associado = td.cd_associado_pd AND tmp.cd_codmeiopagto = '2' AND td.cd_associado_pd <> NULL) -- cond 3

WHERE associado.id_associado = '311';
```

Comment: Replace in all your conditions `...<> NULL` with `... IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @forpas it still didn't work

Comment: You don't clearly say what you want your query to return. (Code that doesn't do what you want doesn't tell us what you want.) Also your writing is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the little bit fault is the way you understand the NULL.
LEFT JOIN already promotes NULL in the first place.
LEFT JOIN is more loosey than INNER JOIN.

In order to get the possible NOT NULL of all your records. You have to divert the NULL condition in bigger query.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_associado AS associado 
INNER JOIN tb_ProdutoComercial AS comercial ON associado.id_prodcomerc_a = comercial.id_prodcomerc
INNER JOIN tb_ProdAnsS4E AS sq ON comercial.id_ProdutoS4E_c = sq.nu_CodProdutoS4E
INNER JOIN tb_meiopagto AS tmp ON associado.id_meiopagto_a = tmp.id_meiopagto

LEFT JOIN tb_pgtoboleto AS tb 
   ON (associado.id_associado = tb.cd_associado_pb AND tmp.cd_codmeiopagto = '3' ) -- cond 1

LEFT JOIN tb_pgtocartao AS tc
    ON (associado.id_associado = tc.cd_associado_pc AND tmp.cd_codmeiopagto = '1') -- cond 2

LEFT JOIN tb_pgtodebito AS td 
   ON (associado.id_associado = td.cd_associado_pd AND tmp.cd_codmeiopagto = '2') -- cond 3

WHERE associado.id_associado = '311'
AND  tb.cd_associado_pb <> NULL   -- condition 1
 AND tc.cd_associado_pc <> NULL -- condition 2
 AND td.cd_associado_pd <> NULL  -- condition 3
;
```

The series of AND condtions is kinda strict. You can apply OR with a set for ( ) parenthesis to change the logic.